# SQLite Database structure for image library

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

I'd like to create an application for managing, searching, and displaying a database of image files, similar to Picasa or Shotwell, but I have little experience with databases. I intend to use SQLite using the Qt framework.

Let's assume 50,000 files. What is the best database table structure to search by the following data? Adding and removing files would be relatively rare while querying and editing would be very common.

1. path to image file
2. path to thumbnail file (this field would not be searchable)
3. various meta data (author, date created, dimensions, rating, file type, etc.)
4. array of tags

If I would like the search to occur as the user types (similar to Picasa or Shotwell), which would require up to several queries per second, should I...

1. query the database once at startup and keep the data in memory?
2. query the database on every update to the search box?
3. a mixture of both?

From what I understand, I should create a table of commonly repeated data (tags, authors, file types) containing foreign keys. Is this a correct assumption? For data that is potentially unique to each file such as creation date or file name, is there an alternative to simply searching through an entire file table?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.